# Bulk update text format for imported drupal nodes

Tags: mysql, drupal-7, drupal-schema

I've been migrating a sites content without much luck: The content was being imported, but the body text not displayed. I just tried to change the input text format, and the content is now displayed. (I guess those are the original values.)

I tried googling for a MySQL command to bulk update the input type, but all seem to be outdated from Drupal 6.

Can anyone help with a command to update all input types on Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Drupal 7 I would highly recommend downloading the feed module from drupal.org and go that route because the posts are imported as blog entries.  Now you will have to go into content and change the text format from filtered-html to full if so desired and place them in groups if you have Organic Groups installed.  However the feed import is pretty straight forward.  If you are importing from WordPress it is easier to use the Wordpress Migration tool and it will be dependent on the migrate module and the migrate extras module.